# Incorrect PR merge in VSTS - the new change disappeared after the merge

Tags: git, merge

I am facing a very strange situation, where:

1. A developer made a change to some file.
2. Merged the change through a Pull Request.
3. The change was removed by the merge.

Now, I know how Git merge recursive strategy works and to the best of my understanding the change should have survived the merge.

Now the gory details. The main commits are:

1. cfff5f5577 - this is where the developer made the change.
2. e2f51c17e7 - this is the PR merge commit. The change disappeared from here.

So, these are the PR commits:

[image]

This is the PR merge commit:

[image]

Now, the essence of the problem is that the changes in cfff5f5577 did not propagate to e2f51c17e7.

According to my understanding the merge diagram is:

```
  +------------ Y -----+ e2f51c17e7
 /                    /
X                    /
 \                  /
  +------ cfff5f5577
```

Where Y is the target of the PR merge and X is the common ancestor.

Y is e2f51c17e7^1, which gives us 462fc3b376:

[image]

And for X I use the merge-base command which yields 483b84e708:

[image]

So, the final merge diagram is:

```
           +------ 462fc3b376 --+ e2f51c17e7
          /                    /
483b84e708                    /
          \                  /
           +------ cfff5f5577
```

Now in order for the change to appear in the merge commit the following should happen (to the best of my knowledge):

1. the relevant lines of code should be unchanged between 483b84e708 and 462fc3b376
2. The relevant lines of code should change between 483b84e708 and cfff5f5577

If that happens, the change would propagate to e2f51c17e7.

**Comparing 483b84e708 to 462fc3b376**

[image]

[image]

So these four lines look identical here.

**Comparing 483b84e708 to cfff5f5577**

[image]

[image]

The change is there.

**Comparing cfff5f5577 to e2f51c17e7**

[image]

[image]

The change is gone!

**Comparing 462fc3b376 to e2f51c17e7**

[image]

It is identical!

**Conclusion**

From this I conclude that auto merge decided to kill the change. Now I understand that my Beyond Compare snapshots may not represent the merge picture accurately, because BC may align rows differently than Git. In which case I am asking - how can I retrace Git merge process to understand why the merge was killed?

This is extremely disturbing because this is the PR merge commit - we cannot review it **before** it is merged into the code base, since it is not part of the PR commits themselves. We are expected to trust it does the right thing. And I believe it does, hence I am completely puzzled here.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: In Github, you actually can inspect the candidate merged code:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/GitHub-Maintaining-a-Project#_pr_refs.

Gitlab appears to have at least part of this via `origin/merge-requests/<number>/head`:

https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/merge_requests/index.md#checkout-merge-requests-locally

Not sure if that gives you everything you need but maybe you'll find more e.g. by fetching `git fetch origin merge-requests/*`

Comment: another thing you can always try for stuff like this is to run the merge yourself in a local environment

Comment: @jsharp - I will try local merge. There is no such branch as merge-requests in VSTS as far as I can see. Maybe I am missing something

Comment: sorry your screenshots looked like gitlab, did not realize VSTS was an azure offering with its own system. i think the best way to find out if they expose these merge branches is to search output of `git ls-remote origin` for something that looks like your merge request id. however yeah when this sort of thing happens i have always seen it reproduce just by running `git checkout <base> && git merge <feature>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me.

When I checked the merge locally it immediately told me that there is a merge conflict. And then it has dawned upon me. We have a Merge Conflict resolution plugin installed. Behold:

[image]

The developer incorrectly resolved the merge conflict. He took the target, instead of taking the source of the merge.

Case closed.